# Array within a Struct; How Can I Make My Code More Succinct?

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and am struggling with coding brevity.

A practice problem gave a table of values (name, ID, and four quizzes for each student) which we were asked to put in a `struct`, then print the info and the quiz average for each student.

While I was able to accomplish this, my code for it is inelegant. I'd like some help on making it more succinct so I can make good coding habits now.

Here's the practice problem:

- Create a data structure to store information on students in a `class`.  For every student, the professor wants to store (for now, this will be expanded later):

  - name  (a string)
  - university id number (integer)
  - quiz scores (an array of 4 float quiz scores)
- Write a program that will initialize the variable in the declaration and then calculate and print the quiz average for every student.

I was able to figure out how to put a float with four values within a struct, but I cannot figure out how to condense the array within the struct to reduce the length of my code.

Further, I coded the values for each student separately, but struggled to get a single print statement to work for all the students, and instead had to include separate print statements for each student. I suspect there's a better way to do this by looping, but I cannot get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    char name[30];
    int id_no;
    float quiz[4];
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    float avg;

    struct student student1;
    strcpy(student1.name,"C,Joe");
    student1.id_no = 999;
    student1.quiz[0] = 10.0;
    student1.quiz[1] = 9.5;
    student1.quiz[2] = 0.0;
    student1.quiz[3] = 10.0;

    struct student student2;
    strcpy(student2.name,"Hernandez, Pete");
    student2.id_no = 784;
    student2.quiz[0] = 10.0;
    student2.quiz[1] = 10.0;
    student2.quiz[2] = 9.0;
    student2.quiz[3] = 10.0;

    struct student student3;
    strcpy(student3.name,"Brownnose, Violet");
    student3.id_no = 999;
    student3.quiz[0] = 7.5;
    student3.quiz[1] = 6.0;
    student3.quiz[2] = 8.5;
    student3.quiz[3] = 7.5;

    {
      printf("Name: %s ",student1.name);
      printf("ID: %d ",student1.id_no);
      avg = 0;
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        printf(" Quiz %d: %.1f ",i,student1.quiz[i]);
        avg = avg + student1.quiz[i];
      }
      avg = avg/4;
      printf("\nAverage quiz score: %.1f\n",avg);
    }
printf("\n");
    {
      printf("Name: %s ",student2.name);
      printf("ID: %d ",student2.id_no);
      avg = 0;
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        printf(" Quiz %d: %.1f ",i,student2.quiz[i]);
        avg = avg + student2.quiz[i];
      }
      avg = avg/4;
      printf("\nAverage quiz score: %.1f\n",avg);
    }
printf("\n");
    {
      printf("Name: %s ",student3.name);
      printf("ID: %d ",student3.id_no);
      avg = 0;
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        printf(" Quiz %d: %.1f ",i,student3.quiz[i]);
        avg = avg + student3.quiz[i];
      }
      avg = avg/4;
      printf("\nAverage quiz score: %.1f\n",avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output results look fine. The method I used for getting there, however, is lacking (notice that I had to use three print statements at the end—one for each student).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: if this program works correctly and you understand it, this might be better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is not fully responsive to the prompt, which says

> [...] *Write a program that will **initialize the variable in the declaration*** [...]

.  Doing as instructed will simplify your code somewhat, just as you are looking to do.  For example:

```
struct student student1 = { .name = "C,Joe", .id_no = 999, .quiz = { 10.0, 9.5, 0.0, 10.0 }};
```

As long as you provide initializers in member-declaration order, without skipping, you can abbreviate that further by omitting the member designators and providing only the initialization values.  I prefer to use the designators, though, as I find it clearer.

> Further, I coded the values for each student separately, but struggled
>   to get a single print statement to work for all the students, and
>   instead had to include separate print statements for each student. I
>   suspect there's a better way to do this by looping, but I cannot get
>   it to work.

If you want to loop, then you need some kind of data structure that supports iteration.  Arrays are the obvious kind, but a linked list could work, too.  Taking the array route, you might avoid individual variables for the students, like so:

```
struct student students[] = {
    { .name = "Alice", .id_no = 42, .quiz = { 1.0, 2.5, 3.0, 0.0 }},
    { .name = "Bob", .id_no = 99, .quiz = { 10.0, 9.5, 8.0, 7.0 }},
    // ...
};
```

You can then loop over the array, operating at each iteration on `students[i]`, for `i` in the range of valid indices of `students`.

Comment: After banging my head against the wall on this one for an embarrassing amount of time, I cannot thank you enough—your solution worked perfectly and, more importantly, improved my understanding. Just to clarify, you wrote "I prefer to use the designators, though, as I find it clearer." By that, do you mean writing out the content such as ".name", "id_no", etc. as oppose to omitting it (I assume these are what you're referring to as "member designators"?

Comment: You are welcome.  And yes, the member designators are the `.name =`, *etc*. parts.  In fact, if for some reason you are stuck with only C90 conformance, then you *must* omit them, as they were a new feature in C99.

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone stumble upon this question after similarly struggling, here's my solution after integrating John Bollinger's incredibly helpful response:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct students{
    char name[30];
    int id_no;
    float quiz[4];
};

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    float runsum;

    struct students student[] = {{ .name = "C,Joe", .id_no = 999, .quiz = { 10.0, 9.5, 0.0, 10.0 }},
    { .name = "Hernandez, Pete", .id_no = 784, .quiz = { 10.0, 10.0, 9.0, 10.0 }},
    { .name = "Brownnose, Violet", .id_no = 332, .quiz = { 7.5, 6.0, 8.5, 7.5 }}
    };

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Name: %s ",student[i].name);
        printf("ID: %d ",student[i].id_no);
        runsum = 0;
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            runsum = runsum + student[i].quiz[j];
        }
        printf(" Quiz average: %.2f\n",runsum/4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```